# Weird behavior of printf in C++ with a newline character

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, printf

This could be simple or lame question. I have been playing with `printf` function in C++. When I execute following code on Debian Wheezy with any 9 character argument (eg:"argument1") ;

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    printf(argv[1]+'\n');

}
```

the out put was;

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=4375
```

Then I checked the environment variable `$SSH_AGENT_PID` and its value is 4375.

Could you please tell me what is going on with my code ? 
(I tried to examine the disassembled code in  gdb. But my assembly knowledge is poor to understand exactly whats going on)

Comment: That code isn't doing what you think it does. Google pointer arithmetic.

Comment: + didn't concatenate strings.

Comment: It probably happened to point into your environment strings. This time.

Comment: If this is C code, why is it tagged C++?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've compiled it with cpp extension

Comment: @shan Then why is it tagged C and why does the text talk about the `printf` function in C?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not sure about the compiler's behavior on bot extensions. I thought may be it has to do with whether it is C or C++. But I realize I was wrong now.

Comment: @shan I fixed the tags and the question. Next time, please be more careful. You'll get much better answers to your questions if you clearly specify what language you are using. (The best answers to this question are completely different for the two languages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain what you are seeing from `argv[1] + '\n'`. This is *pointer* plus *integer*  (character constants have type `int` in C).

The definition of that in C is that the pointer is advanced by as many units as are in the integer. `\n` is `10` in ASCII so this will advance the pointer by 10 characters. If your string is shorter than 10 then you're now reading whatever is in memory beyond the end of that string.

The fix suggested by Ben Braun is a good one; another option is `puts( argv[1] );` which will output the string without doing any printf-like translations, and output a newline.

Answer (score 4):

Simple fix:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

This is an improvement on your code for two reasons: First, it's generally a good idea to have the first argument to printf be a string constant, as this prevents printf code injection. Second, it fixes the bug because as @Captain Oblivious pointed out, the code you wrote doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: ok then. please tell me how it accesses environment variable?

Comment: Mark Ransom's answer touches on some of this.

Comment: To elaborate - the value of '\n' is 10 (decimal), so you are taking the pointer to the characters of the first argument, offsetting this by 10 bytes, and then printing from there. If argv[1] is more than 9 characters long, all you would see is the substring of argv[1] taking out the first 9 characters. When argv[1] is less, behavior is undefined and you print characters from (apparently) the environmental variables. (Edit: Also see Matt McNabb's answer)

Comment: Stroustrup doesn't recommend to use stdio package in c++. It's been superseded by iostream. You had better not mesh c stuff with c++ without knowing the limitations of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

`char*` strings and string literals and character literals can't be added together. You need to create a new string and use `strcat` to concatenate one to the other.

What you're actually getting is undefined behavior, since you're adding some constant to a pointer and not checking that you've passed the end of the string. It's only a coincidence that the output was readable at all and that your program didn't crash.

If C++ is an option you can use `std::string` instead, which *does* allow `+` to concatenate two strings.

Comment: I think you misread `'` as `"` in the question  (or OP edited it in the grace period). Adding two pointers is constraint violation BTW.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it was originally single quotes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks, you're absolutely right. I've made an edit to fix things.

Comment: Actually, not undefined at all. `'\n'` is simply the integer 10, which is perfectly legal to add to a character pointer, thus making it print the 10th and subsequent characters of the string (assuming the string is that long--if the string is too short, then you're accessing random memory and will print garbage).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker the undefined behavior is caused by going past the end of the string, not the simple addition itself.

Comment: Yes, if the string is too short you'll print garbage. But it's very unlikely you'll get a segfault or similar--most compilers are happy to print whatever they find at the address given, as it is likely to be in the correct memory section.